# $A \in L(V)$ where $V$ is a FDVS. Prove that there is an invertible $Q$ such that $AQ$ is a projection.

Tags: linear-algebra

On P. 94 of Halmos' FDVS, you will find the following theorem:

Corresponding to any linear transformation $A$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, there is an invertible linear transformation $P$ for which $PA$ is a projection.

After presenting the proof, he wrote, "Consideration of the adjoint of A, together with the reflexivity of $V$, shows that we may also find an invertible $Q$ for which $AQ$ is a projection".  I mimicked Halmos' proof regarding $PA$ and founded the $Q$ such that $AQ$ is a projection; the proof is presented below.  However, how do I prove that $AQ$ is a projection via the adjoint of $A$?

Let $R$ be the range of $A$, $N$ the null-space of $A$, Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, we can set $dimR = \rho$ and $dimN = n-\rho$. Let $\{ x_1, x_2 ... x_\rho \}$ be a basis of $R$; extend it to $\{ x_1, x_2 ... x_\rho, x_{\rho+1} ... x_n \}$, a basis of V.  For all $k = 1$ to $\rho$, $x_k = Ay_k$.  Now, let $\{ y_{\rho+1}, y_{\rho+2} ... y_n \}$ be a basis of $N$.  We claim that $\{ y_1, y_2 ... y_\rho, y_{\rho+1} ... y_n \}$, a basis of V.  Set $\sum_{k=1}^n {a_k}{y_k} = 0$.  On one hand, $\{ y_{\rho+1}, y_{\rho+2} ... y_n \}$ is already linear independent; $a_k = 0$ for all $k = \rho+1$ to $n$.  Apply $A$ to $\sum_{k=1}^\rho {a_k}{y_k}$, and we'll have $\sum_{k=1}^\rho {a_k}{x_k} = 0$, entailing that $a_k = 0$ for all $k = 1$ to $\rho$.  $\{ y_1, y_2 ... y_\rho, y_{\rho+1} ... y_n \}$ is a linearly independent set of $n$ vectors, so it is a basis of $V$.

Let $ Q \in L(V)$ be defined by $Qx_k = y_k$ for all $ k = 1$ to $n$.  Clearly, Q is linear and one-to-one.  Furthermore, because $dimV = dimR(Q)$, $Q$ is also onto.  $Q$ is invertible.  
Pick $x \in X_1 = $ span$\{x_1, x_2 ... x_\rho\}$.  $AQx$ = $\sum_{k=1}^\rho {a_k}AQ{x_k}$ = $\sum_{k=1}^\rho {a_k}{x_k}$ = $x$. 
Then take $x \in X_2 =$ span$\{x_{\rho+1}, x_{\rho+2} ... x_n\}$.  $AQx$= $\sum_{k=\rho+1}^n {a_k}Ay_k$ = $0$. 
As a result, $AQ$ is a projection onto $X_1$ along $X_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rephrase the statement of the theorem with different variables: We have that for any linear transformation $T$ in a FDVS $W$ we can find $P$ such that $PT$ is a projection.

In particular, we can set $T=A'$, the adjoint of $A$, and $W=V'$, the dual space of $V$. We get that for some operator P (in $V'$) the operator $PA'$ is a projection. Taking the adjoint yields $$(PA')'=(A')'P'=AQ,$$
where, due to reflexivity, we can identify $A$ with $(A')'$ and $P'$ with an operator $Q$ in $V$, instead of considering operators in $(V')'$.

To show that this is a projection, just use $(AQ)^2=((PA')')^2=((PA')^2)'=(PA')'=AQ.$

Your proof is an alternative to this adjoint-mongering.

Comment: I did not realize that you can do that .... beginning with $PA'$ and then taking the adjoint to get back $AP' = AQ$.  But if you can justify that $Q$ is invertible and $AQ$ is a projection, then there is no big deal.  Thanks!